# Animating sub-items in compound elements

Tags: css-animations, polymer

After following the polymer tutorial to create [this](http://www.polymer-project.org/samples/tutorial/finished/index.html) I'd like to add some animation.

I would like for favorited posts to fade out when they are un-favorited instead of just disappearing.

I'm very new to polymer and unsure of where/how I should do this.

My first though was to edit the post-card element, I imagine this is the relevant code:

```
  Polymer('post-card', {
    publish: {
      favorite: {
        value: false,
        reflect: true
      }
    },
    favoriteTapped: function(event, detail, sender) {
      this.favorite = !this.favorite;
      this.fire('favorite-tap');
    }
  });
```

I'm a little lost from there though.